# Parse response in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When i sending some data on host:

```
r = urllib2.Request(url, data = data, headers = headers)
page = urllib2.urlopen(r)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), fromEncoding="cp-1251")
print page.read()
```

i have something like this:

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"spsr","theme_token":"kRHUhchUVpxAMYL8Y8IoyYIcX0cPrUstziAi8gSmMYk","css":[]},"ajax":{"edit-submit":{"callback":"spsr_calculator_form_ajax","wrapper":"calculator_form","method":"replaceWith","event":"mousedown","keypress":true,"url":"\/ru\/system\/ajax","submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"submit"}}}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":null,"selector":null,"data":"\u003cdiv id=\"calculator_form\"\u003e\u003cform action=\"\/ru\/service\/calculator\" method=\"post\" id=\"spsr-calculator-form\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\"\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cinput id=\"edit-from-ship-region-id\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"from_ship_region_id\" value=\"\" \/\u003e\n\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_build_id\" value=\"form-0RK_WFli4b2kUDTxpoqsGPp14B_0yf6Fz9x7UK-T3w8\" \/\u003e\n\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_id\" value=\"spsr_calculator_form\" \/\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003cdiv class=\"bg_p\"\u003e \n\u0421\u0435\u0439\u0447\u0430\u0441 \u0412\u044b... bla bla bla
```

but i want have something, like this:

```
<html><h1>bla bla bla</h1></html>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: How about adding some tags and text and title words to indicate what you are actually doing (not simply "parse response in python", which is way more generic than your actual question).  Also, please format your second block of code to use multiple lines rather than one run-on.

Comment: Have you executed your example? You are calling page.read() twice, which makes no sense in my opinion. And what are you doing with `soup`? It's not used at all?!

Comment: agreed with @achim that something is wrong here. are you actually calling a JSON ? or maybe you should just print the soup and not page.read(). either way would guide you in a better route than the current one

Answer (score 3):

The answer you are getting is very likely encoded in JSON. If this is true then using BeautifulSoup doesn't make any sense (it is a HTML/XML parser). If you have JSON data you will need to use a JSON parser. Calling `page.read()` twice doesn't make any sense either since it won't return you anything sane after the first call.

Rewriting your request part we get:

```
r = urllib2.Request(url, data = data, headers = headers)
page = urllib2.urlopen(r)
data = page.read()
```

Now instead of an HTML parser, we need to use a JSON parser. This can be done with `json` library (in Python since 2.6):

```
import json
decoded_data = json.loads(data)
```

Now, just locate which part of the model you want to extract. Considering your example and give you want to print out the section with "blabla", you can write:

```
result = unicode(decoded_data[1][u'data'])
```

For debugging try:

```
print result
```

Comment: don't use json - use simplejson. don't use urllib2 use requests. better python libraries for the job